# locomotive scroll disable the scroll of my page

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, locomotive-scroll

When I put this function : **const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
smooth: true
});**
The scroll of my page not working and i can't scroll into the page, when I put this function in comment, the scroll is working again.
I don't know why locomotive scroll disable the scroll in the page, so do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is probably due to not setting the attribute data-scroll-container to an element. Please add data-scroll-container to an element to trigger scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the section(s) in your data-scroll-container, otherwise it will not work. Your main div should have the data-scroll-container attribute, plus each section should have data-scroll-section attribute. Example:

```html
<div class="container" data-scroll-container>
  <div class="section" data-scroll-section>
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-scroll-section>
    <h2>Something else</h2>
    <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
```

There is a good example video I've found which provides a detailed application.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-ks1-dzKEw